# SAX parser in java

Tags: java, parsing, sax

can SAX parser handle self closing tag? or will it cause an error?
eg `<br/> or <hr/>`

Comment: Wouldn't it be easy to just try it out?

Comment: Yes, it can. But I think you ask this question for some other purposes. Do you want to share it here? Let's get to the point directly.

Answer (score 3):

```
<br/> or <hr/>
```

are called empty tags. SAX parser will not give an error.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the SAX parser in XML rather than HTML mode then yes, it can handle self-closing tags. **Note:** self-closing tags are valid XML but technically not valid HTML.

**Valid HTML:** `<br> <div></div>`

**Valid XML:** `<br/> <div></div> <div/>`

Comment: @cletus : what is ment my parser in html and xml mode. Can u giv  me a link to basics and advanced SAX parser tutorials in java?